# Is there a way to convert an Avro file published to a Kafka topic to a flat SQL table in python?

Tags: python, sql, apache-kafka, avro

I have an Avro schema (avsc file) and data published in kafka topics in Avro format which I need to convert to a flat SQL table.

Answer (score 0):

If the data was produced by one of the Confluent Avro serializers, you can use their Kafka Connect JDBC Sink to write to a SQL database of your choice (such as sqlite if you literally want files)

Otherwise, you're going to need to write your own Python code for this use-case